how to backup Room Entity with Date datatype to Firebase Realtime Database (Kotlin)
I need to send a copy of my Room Database table to the Firebase Realtime Database, but it didn't work when having date datatype on my room database.
I am using Kotlin and Android Studio. please, I need a clear way to send a list of objects that have a date datatype from Room to Firebase Realtime Database.
Here is the structure of my data

@Entity
data class Bill(
   @PrimaryKey
    val id:Date,
    var name:String,
    var category: String,
    var price:Long,
    var count:Int,
    var total:Long,
    var date: LocalDate
)

I have a reference on firebase having the same variables but don't know what datatype to choose for id and date variables or how to convert from room to be accepted in firebase realtime database.
I searched a lot and didn't find a clear structure of how to solve it.
I know that firebase database doesn't accept date datatype but I am expecting there is a way to convert date type when sending to firebase. I am sending it as a full List of objects not an object.
thanks


I don't know what datatype to choose for the id and date variables or how to convert from room to be accepted in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Unfortunately, the Date and the LocalDate are not supported data types in the Firebase Realtime Database. What you can use instead is a ServerValue#TIMESTAMP as explained in my answer from the following post:

I need to add current date to firebase Realtime database with other data and retrieve all data with date in kotlin android

Or any other Unix timestamp value which represents the time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds.
Edit:
There is no way you can generate a timestamp client-side. Remember that FieldValue values are just tokens that are interpreted on the Firebase server. So when using Firestore, you can use a Date object instead. So you can save all the operations to Room and then synchronize the data at the end of the day with Firestore.
I'm not sure why would you implement such a mechanism, I would go ahead with saving the data from the first time in the Cloud.

hi Alex , thanks for reply. but I already have a list on room database that have date datatype and need to send this full list to firebase

There is no way you can add in the Firebase Realtime Database fields that are not supported. However, if you want to work with Date objects, then I recommend you move the data from Room to Cloud Firestore. So I think that this answer might help.

my project is creating list of bills offline on room database and and the end of the day the cashier man send the full list to firebase online database so the owner can cache it in his room database on his personal device. so the date should have already been created offline with client-server side and no need to add again with server-side

I am currently generating bill id ( id:Date = Date.from(Instant.now())  ) and createdAt (date:LocalDate = LocalDate.now()I) on my Room database with help of converter class .  I think it would be better to move all the operations to firestore cloud as you suggested, I know that when working online with realtime database we use push() to get a unique id but don't know how does that work offline. if you send me a link of how to get unique id when working offline with firestore cloud would be appreciated. thanks Alex, the information you shared really helpful

You can use push() in the Realtime Database or add() in Firestore, to generate unique IDs. Both are generated on the client. So you can go ahead with this idea.
